# Are there any ways to corrupt a google spreadsheet such that it can never be recovered by any means?

Tags: google-sheets

I have not shared it with anyone at any point save for my alternate gmail account. It has very, very personal information stored within and I realised immediately after creating it that I would rather not have it stored where it cannot be physically burned and I do not see us beating chaotic determinism and being able to bring back a burned paper after a century of it being burned. I want it gone. I will learn the means necessary if I am taught here. I do not know what else to put here. I do not think that there is any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a free Gmail account, it should be enough to put the file in the Drive trash and empty the trash.

If you are using a Google Workspace domain account, your administrator may have set up data loss prevention rules that prevent irrecoverable deletion. See [Google Vault](https://workspace.google.com/products/vault/) and [Retention and eDiscovery for organizations](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462365).